# Image Gallery Manager for PHP and MySQL?

Tags: image, gallery

Can anyone recommend a plugin or library that allows people to upload images which automatically gets cropped and resized?  I don't mind editting some config files to specify how images should be cropped and resized.

Additionally, after uploading, the front end user should be able to drag and drop for re-ordering.

Can someone recommend something that works with php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i built something custom